# crash Xamarin IOS app on only some device with type EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, xamarin, crash

Help, please! My xamarin IOS app was crashed on some device. That application is available from the App Store and works correctly, but there had appeals for crash application. I can not figure out what the reason is. If someone knows how to decrypt these logos, please respond.
There are my .crash-file:

```
Incident Identifier: 854558AB-E175-4A50-ACC0-9BA892F25AA3
CrashReporter Key:   5086dbbd061185ea7331aafe74879503a9e3532f
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,3
Process:             MyAppiOS [1254]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/051ABEFA-746C-4D88-B0CA-00B2525802F3/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS
Identifier:         my.mobile
Version:             81 (3.2.3)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:          my.mobile [656]
```

.......

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4309762048
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000100e1c000-0000000100e20000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...pp/MyAppiOS

Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x185c7e364 __exceptionPreprocess + 124 (NSException.m:166)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x184ec4528 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:521)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x185c7e2ac +[NSException raise:format:] + 116 (NSException.m:141)
3   UIKit                           0x18f60f098 -[UIToolbar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:] + 80 (UIToolbar.m:529)
4   MyAppiOS                        0x1012639ec 0x100e1c000 + 4487660
5   MyAppiOS                        0x1012e5db8 0x100e1c000 + 5021112
6   MyAppiOS                        0x101d6c8d8 0x100e1c000 + 16058584
7   MyAppiOS                        0x100eb9f5c 0x100e1c000 + 647004
8   MyAppiOS                        0x100fefac4 0x100e1c000 + 1915588
9   MyAppiOS                        0x101e36c3c 0x100e1c000 + 16886844
10  MyAppiOS                        0x101eb2334 0x100e1c000 + 17392436
11  MyAppiOS                        0x101eb2294 0x100e1c000 + 17392276
12  MyAppiOS                        0x100e20204 0x100e1c000 + 16900
13  MyAppiOS                        0x100e2b104 0x100e1c000 + 61700
14  UIKit                           0x18f234ae8 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1040 (UIViewController.m:3133)
15  UIKit                           0x18f2dbf70 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 76 (UINavigationController.m:6345)
16  UIKit                           0x18f2db410 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 196 (UINavigationController.m:6380)
17  UIKit                           0x18f2dae14 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 1168 (UINavigationController.m:6601)
18  UIKit                           0x18f2da890 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 164 (UINavigationController.m:6872)
19  UIKit                           0x18f2da790 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188 (UILayoutContainerView.m:87)
20  UIKit                           0x1a4ecdc18 -[UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility layoutSubviews] + 52 (UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility.m:114)
21  UIKit                           0x18f231f00 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1276 (UIView.m:15124)
22  QuartzCore                      0x189cc1998 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184 (CALayer.mm:9302)
23  QuartzCore                      0x189cc5b20 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 332 (CALayer.mm:9182)
24  QuartzCore                      0x189c3236c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 336 (CALayer.mm:2416)
25  QuartzCore                      0x189c59b90 CA::Transaction::commit() + 540 (CATransactionInternal.mm:425)
26  QuartzCore                      0x189c5a9d0 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92 (CATransactionInternal.mm:795)
27  CoreFoundation                  0x185c25edc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1824)
28  CoreFoundation                  0x185c23894 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412 (CFRunLoop.c:1934)
29  CoreFoundation                  0x185c23e50 __CFRunLoopRun + 1292 (CFRunLoop.c:2948)
30  CoreFoundation                  0x185b43e58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
31  GraphicsServices                0x1879f0f84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
32  UIKit                           0x18f29867c UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3956)
33  MyAppiOS                        0x101270700 0x100e1c000 + 4540160
34  MyAppiOS                        0x1012d6584 0x100e1c000 + 4957572
35  MyAppiOS                        0x100eafb7c 0x100e1c000 + 605052
36  MyAppiOS                        0x100fefac4 0x100e1c000 + 1915588
37  MyAppiOS                        0x101e36c3c 0x100e1c000 + 16886844
38  MyAppiOS                        0x101eb2334 0x100e1c000 + 17392436
39  MyAppiOS                        0x101eb55d8 0x100e1c000 + 17405400
40  MyAppiOS                        0x101e1a124 0x100e1c000 + 16769316
41  MyAppiOS                        0x101f6a904 0x100e1c000 + 18147588
42  MyAppiOS                        0x100e55208 0x100e1c000 + 233992
43  libdyld.dylib                   0x18566056c start + 4

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001857902e8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001858a52f8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396 (pthread.c:1484)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001856ff060 __abort + 152 (abort.c:128)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001856fefc8 abort + 152 (abort.c:99)
4   MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101f63bc4 0x100e1c000 + 18119620
5   MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101e6eda4 0x100e1c000 + 17116580
6   MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101e26eb8 0x100e1c000 + 16821944
7   MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101e25cc8 0x100e1c000 + 16817352
8   MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101e1d8d8 0x100e1c000 + 16783576
9   MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101011008 0x100e1c000 + 2052104
10  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101f63a10 0x100e1c000 + 18119184
11  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101271284 0x100e1c000 + 4543108
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185c7e6d8 __handleUncaughtException + 628 (NSException.m:219)
13  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000184ec4804 _objc_terminate() + 112 (objc-exception.mm:656)
14  libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000184eb454c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:66)
15  libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000184eb3ea8 __cxa_throw + 136 (cxa_exception.cpp:130)
16  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000184ec465c objc_exception_throw + 364 (objc-exception.mm:546)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185c7e2ac +[NSException raise:format:] + 116 (NSException.m:141)
18  UIKit                           0x000000018f60f098 -[UIToolbar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:] + 80 (UIToolbar.m:529)
19  MyAppiOS                        0x00000001012639ec 0x100e1c000 + 4487660
20  MyAppiOS                        0x00000001012e5db8 0x100e1c000 + 5021112
21  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101d6c8d8 0x100e1c000 + 16058584
22  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000100eb9f5c 0x100e1c000 + 647004
23  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000100fefac4 0x100e1c000 + 1915588
24  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101e36c3c 0x100e1c000 + 16886844
25  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101eb2334 0x100e1c000 + 17392436
26  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101eb2294 0x100e1c000 + 17392276
27  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000100e20204 0x100e1c000 + 16900
28  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000100e2b104 0x100e1c000 + 61700
29  UIKit                           0x000000018f234ae8 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1040 (UIViewController.m:3133)
30  UIKit                           0x000000018f2dbf70 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 76 (UINavigationController.m:6345)
31  UIKit                           0x000000018f2db410 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 196 (UINavigationController.m:6380)
32  UIKit                           0x000000018f2dae14 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 1168 (UINavigationController.m:6601)
33  UIKit                           0x000000018f2da890 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 164 (UINavigationController.m:6872)
34  UIKit                           0x000000018f2da790 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188 (UILayoutContainerView.m:87)
35  UIKit                           0x00000001a4ecdc18 -[UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility layoutSubviews] + 52 (UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility.m:114)
36  UIKit                           0x000000018f231f00 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1276 (UIView.m:15124)
37  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189cc1998 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184 (CALayer.mm:9302)
38  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189cc5b20 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 332 (CALayer.mm:9182)
39  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189c3236c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 336 (CALayer.mm:2416)
40  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189c59b90 CA::Transaction::commit() + 540 (CATransactionInternal.mm:425)
41  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189c5a9d0 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92 (CATransactionInternal.mm:795)
42  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185c25edc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1824)
43  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185c23894 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412 (CFRunLoop.c:1934)
44  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185c23e50 __CFRunLoopRun + 1292 (CFRunLoop.c:2948)
45  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185b43e58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
46  GraphicsServices                0x00000001879f0f84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
47  UIKit                           0x000000018f29867c UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3956)
48  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101270700 0x100e1c000 + 4540160
49  MyAppiOS                        0x00000001012d6584 0x100e1c000 + 4957572
50  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000100eafb7c 0x100e1c000 + 605052
51  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000100fefac4 0x100e1c000 + 1915588
52  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101e36c3c 0x100e1c000 + 16886844
53  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101eb2334 0x100e1c000 + 17392436
54  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101eb55d8 0x100e1c000 + 17405400
55  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101e1a124 0x100e1c000 + 16769316
56  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101f6a904 0x100e1c000 + 18147588
57  MyAppiOS                        0x0000000100e55208 0x100e1c000 + 233992
58  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018566056c start + 4

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185790d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001858a3080 _pthread_wqthread + 1288 (pthread.c:0)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001858a2b6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001857900f0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001858a6ce4 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640 (pthread_cond.c:579)
2   MyAppiOS                        0x0000000101f32424 0x100e1c000 + 17916964
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001858a42b4 _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001858a4180 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001858a2b74 thread_start + 4
```

Comment: There is no detailed message to show the error cause, it seems like something went wrong with the constraints.

Comment: Cole Xia, I added code. Can you help me?